# Jquery Datatable - AJAX- No records handler

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am loading data into my datatable using ajax. This is the code:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable( {

"responsive": false,
"pageLength": 25,
"ajax": "/pull",
} );
```

And everything works good ,but if there are no records from the server I see the alert. So, I don't want to see it and I am using the following code to catch the error:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = function ( settings, helpPage, message ) { 
            console.log(message);
        };
```

and it works perfect, but I still see "loading..." message in datatable. Is there a way to change this message if there are no records from the server ? was trying to use

```
"language": { "emptyTable": "My Custom Message On Empty Table" }
```

But it doesn't work, I still see the "loading..." in the middle of the table.

Will be thankful for your support,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you need to return empty list from the backend "/pull" not null

Comment: I am doing this, empty object is in the following format: data = { 'data':[] }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with data source option inside ajax call

```
"ajax": {
          url: URL,
          dataSrc: 'data name(where the table should look for elements)'
        },
```

because it might be looking for data pointer that's why you see still loading

Comment: thank you , I've changed settings to your recommendation but still see the same error

Comment: sorry typo mistake change  data to to dataSrc in key